# Loop and concatenate an array in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to loop an array and concatenate the non null values to a single variable. Needless to say I am new to XSLT. Please see the code that I wrote and let me know the best way to do this.

\ is to be appended at the end and also I have to add a separator * between the values. If * and \ are coming together, then only \ should come and we can omit the *. I believe the logic is correct. The syntax is the issue.

Thanks,
Anoop

```
<xsl:variable name="secondsegmentarray">
    <item>Data/Attribute1</item>
    <item>Data/Attribute2</item>
    <item>Data/Attribute3</item>
    <item>Data/Attribute4</item>
    <item>Data/Attribute5</item>
    <item>Data/Attribute6</item>
    <item>Data/Attribute7</item>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="secondsegment">
    <xsl:value-of select="'\'">
    <xsl:for-each select="secondsegmentarray/item">
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$secondsegmentarray.item = '' and secondsegment='\'"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="$secondsegmentarray.item = not('') and secondsegment='\'"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat($secondsegmentarray.item,secondsegment)"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="$secondsegmentarray.item = not('') and secondsegment!='\'"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat($secondsegmentarray.item,'*',secondsegment)"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="$secondsegmentarray.item = '' and secondsegment!='\'"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat('*',secondsegment)"/>
         </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:variable/>
```

Comment: can you give the expected output for something? And compare with the current output/list any errors you get?

Comment: sure @RAB. Meantime can you tell me if the syntax is right?

Comment: If this is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, then your `$secondsegmentarray` will be of [Result Tree Fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) type (the worst decision about the language specification). And then, of course, you cannot iterate over a Result Tree Fragment (from the spec): *"An operation is permitted on a result tree fragment only if that operation would be permitted on a string **[..]**. In particular, it is not permitted to use the `/`, `//`, and `[]` operators on result tree fragments"*.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but too long to fit in a comment. You have numerous syntax issues, starting with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="secondsegmentarray/item">
```

which is:

- missing a `$` character to identify a variable, and:
- trying to process a *result-tree-fragment* without converting it to a
  *node-set* first.

The correct syntax would be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($secondsegmentarray)/item">
```

afer declaring:

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
```

in the header.

Next, within the `xsl:for-each` instruction you are in the context of `item`. This means that any tests related to the current `item` need to reference the current node, for example:

```
 <xsl:when test=". = ''">
```

Your attempted use of `$secondsegmentarray.item` is meaningless in XPath/XSLT.

In addition, you are referencing the `secondsegment` variable (again, without the required `$` prefix) in the definition of the variable itself. This, of course, cannot work.

There may be more, but these stand out.